# PDF with internal links gets very slow in OSX after Ghostscript compression

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I'm using Ghostscript to reduce the file size of PDF files that I generate from webpages with Puppeteer. It's all working great, only when I start adding internal links in the PDF (to jump to different pages) the PDF gets very slow and close to unusable on OS X (especially in the 'Preview' application). This only happens after the Ghostscript conversion, the raw output of Puppeteer is working fine (but the file size is too big).

I'm running the following command.

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=${outputFile} ${inputFile}
```

Is there a way to keep the PDF working correctly in the OS X Preview application when using internal links?

Comment: Without seeing an example file it's essentially impossible to tell. Before one could make any recommendations we'd need to try and determine why the output file is slow. Note that Ghostscript's pdfwrite device does not compress PDF files. The output file bears no real relationship to the input file, though the appearance should be the same.

Comment: @KenS An example output file can be found here [link](https://3rdfloorcoding.nl/pdf/example.pdf) By the way, it is working great in for example Chrome or Firefox on my Mac, but when I open it with the 'Preview' application it's (almost) not working.

Comment: OK so that's the Ghostscript output, which is whizzy in every PDF consumer I have (not on a Mac so don't have Preview). I'd really need to see the PDF file that was sent as the input to Ghostscript in order to be able to have any chance of seeing what is different. To be honest, this feels like a bug in Preview.

Comment: Well there are some gigantic images in there. The decompressed file is 36MB. There's a bunch of transparency involved as well, which might be relevant. The actual Link annotations don't seem like they should be a problem though. I can't see why Preview would go slow with those. Hmm there is an odd "/File 4" key in the dictionary. I can't see why that would cause Preview a problem, but it's worth checking to see if it's in the original file.

Comment: The input file can be found here [link](https://3rdfloorcoding.nl/pdf/example_input.pdf). The "/File 4" key doesn't seem to exist there, any idea what can cause this appearing in the output?

Comment: Right at the moment, no, but I will certainly try and find out.

Comment: The /File is generated because of the reuse of keys by Adobe. They use /F to mean both flags and file in different cases. In this case there's confusion. However, this does not seem to be anything to do with the problem. If I drop the annotations when creating the output file it is just as slow (for me, on a Mac, running macOS 10.14, using Preview) as when it contains annotations. Whatever it is that Preview is struggling with I don't believe it is the Link annotation (your 'internal links'). I tried removing them from the original and recreating; same result.

Comment: Dropping the transparency (which seems to have no effect on the appearance of the file) makes it much faster, but I've no idea if this is the source of the problem. Whatever it is, it seems to be unique to Mac Preview.